# Can 'system' object be in a use case diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case, use-case-diagram

I'm making a scheduler viewer.

Is putting a system on the opposite side of the user possible like an attached photo?

I know that a person can be there but the system is not a person so I'm asking:)

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An actor may indeed be a person (your actor on the left) or a system (your actor on the right).

However, an actor is always external to the system you are modelling.  So it can be a different system (i.e. an independent system which is interfaced with your `Schedule Viewer` system), but not the subject of the diagram (so it can't be `Schedule Viewer` system itself).

**Important remark**: I assume that you left the rectangle empty, because your question is only about actors and that in reality you have some use-cases inside.  If not, the use-cases would be something fundamental that is missing ;-).